# Firebase Architecture for a single Domain/Company with several independent Business Areas?

Tags: firebase

We want to move our entire IT side of the business onto firebase but need to find the right architectural approach before we do so.

**Here's our company and business setup:**

1. one company with one domain i.e. example.com
2. several business areas independent from each other. For example: one sells bananas, another one is about facility services, yet another one about local transport services & repair
3. the same customer can be customer to one or more of those business areas i.e. we have centralized billing, centralized auth with SSO, centralized customer relation management etc.
4. every business area (e.g. selling bananas) has a web as well as it's mobile versions of the app (iOS/Android) aiding that particular business area

**How do I map that company with its many business areas onto firebase?**

- Do I have one project per business area (e.g. selling bananas) containing the three app versions (two mobile, one web) of the specific area and one project that has all the stuff needed for central user management (#3 from above)?
- What are my limitations regarding number of projects? If every business area has a staging project for its App then we'll have twice as many projects as we have business areas...
- Do I pay per project or per account usage i.e. we would have one account with at least four projects I guess?
- Can I have my domains laid out like this

  - example.com/bananas
  - example.com/facility-services
  - example.com/local-transport-and-repair

Thanks a lot for some insight in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

There's really no direct way to answer this question but Firebase is more than capable of handling this use case within a single project. Doing it that way allows for one user base and if needed, resources can be easily shared between 'departments'

Conceptually, it's pretty straight forward; but we don't have a lot of specific info to go on in the question so here's one example.

Supposed this is a fictuous company that distributes bananas as well as offers banana services for facilities and repairs and maintains banana trucks. We'll call this company; Real Ap-Peel.

```
real-apPeel
  sell_banana_div
     //here we store all data about selling bananas

  facility_services_div
     //here we store the data about facility services

  services_repair_div
     //here we store service and repair data

  users //all users
    uid_0:
      div: 
       sell_banana_div: true
    uid_1:
      div: 
       facility_services_div: true
    uid_2:
      div:
        sell_banana_div: true
        services_repair_div: true
```

In the above setup for our company, we have three separate divisions with their own subset of data. We also have one unified users node to track the users and a child called 'div' which will determine what division that user belongs to.

The last user, uid_2 belongs to two divisions and can therefore access data in the sell_bananas_div as well as the services_repair_div. Handling accessing data in both divisions is done through code and enforced through Firebase Rules.

If you NEVER need to share ANY data between any of the divisions, then there's no reason to have a combined structure like this so go ahead and split it out into separate apps.

However...

Combining data lets you have one app, one code base and one set of users which makes it considerably more maintainable and expandable.

You asked the following:

> Do I have one project per business area (e.g. selling bananas)
>   containing the three app versions (two mobile, one web) of the
>   specific area and one project that has all the stuff needed for
>   central user management (#3 from above)?

All of that is combined into one app, per my above example, and can be any combo or mobile or web.

> What are my limitations regarding number of projects? If every
>   business area has a staging project for its App then we'll have twice
>   as many projects as we have business areas...

Issue eliminated as it's just one project

> Do I pay per project or per account usage i.e. we would have one
>   account with at least four projects I guess?

This is more of a direct question to Firebase if you choose this path. Contact support@firebase.com

> Can I have my domains laid out like this example.com/bananas
>   example.com/facility-services example.com/local-transport-and-repair

My above example pretty much does that - a single realappeel.com and then the references to the child nodes are  realappeel.com/sell_banana_div etc.

I hope this isn't too far off the question. If so, post and comment and I will update (or delete if its waaaaaay off base!)

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for answering. Compliance reasons (export control etc.) require us to have our departments in separate projects and thus databases (user data can be shared, but data belonging to two or more departments cannot reside inside the same database).